# operator does not exist: interval < date

Tags: postgresql, date, interval

I want to do the following comparison :

```sql
IF ( V_C_CRITERE2.DATE_FIN_SOUHAITEE - TO_DATE(V_SEUIL_ALERT) < CURRENT_DATE) THEN
```

**DATE_FIN_SOUHAITEE** is a DATE.

But a get this error :

```
operator does not exist: interval < date
```

How can i do the comparison?

Comment: What data type is `V_SEUIL_ALERT`?

Comment: it's a VARCHAR(100)

Comment: Storing date values in a varchar column is a huge mistake to begin with. But given the error message it seems that `DATE_FIN_SOUHAITEE` is really a `timestamp`. But in any case: your expression doesn't make sense. Subtracting one date from another returns an integer (=number of days) or if one of them is a timestamp, the result is an `interval` (e.g. `3 days 16 hours 10 minutes 5 seconds)`. Comparing that to a `date` value (`2020-04-22`)  doesn't make sense. What exactly are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: What i want to do is to compare the DATE which i will get from :  ```V_C_CRITERE2.DATE_FIN_SOUHAITEE - TO_DATE(V_SEUIL_ALERT)``` with the ```CURRENT_DATE``` .What changes can i do to make to comparison work ??

Comment: As I already explained: `V_C_CRITERE2.DATE_FIN_SOUHAITEE - TO_DATE(V_SEUIL_ALERT)` will not return a date. The difference between two dates is a _duration_, not a date. What do you expect as the result for `'2020-03-19' - '2019-10-27'`

Comment: What i want to do exactly is to migrate this oracle expression : ```IF ( V_C_CRITERE2.DATE_FIN_SOUHAITEE - V_SEUIL_ALERT < sysdate ) THEN``` TO POSTGRESQL

Comment: That expression doesn't make sense in Oracle either if both columns are DATEs. The only thing that would make sense is if `V_SEUIL_ALERT` was a number (not a date)

Comment: I just checked in the Database and there are some values which are numbers. So does it do exactly if it is a number ?

Comment: If `V_SEUIL_ALERT` is a number, then yes that expression is valid - but why did you use `to_date()` then? (And aso in this case: storing numbers in a VARCHAR column is a **huge** mistake and **will** bite you rather sooner than later)

Comment: Because in the database there are some values which are stored as dates. Given that ```V_SEUIL_ALERT``` is a number when i CAST it to a numeric i get the error : ```operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone - numeric``` in POSTGRESQL. How can i produce the same thing is postgresql ?

Comment: What does that number represent? Days? Hours? Minutes? Years?

Comment: it represents years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question states that `DATE_FIN_SOUHAITEE` is a DATE, the error message "*operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone - numeric*" makes it clear that it really is a `timestamp`. In Postgres - unlike Oracle - a `timestamp` is something substantially different than a `date` (in Oracle they are more or less the same thing - they just differ in the precision).

In Postgres you can only subtract an `interval` from a `timestamp`, and you can subtract integer values from a `date`

If V_SEUIL_ALERT is indeed a varchar that stores a number that represents years, you need to convert that string value to a proper interval in order to be able to subtract it from a `timestamp`:

```
V_C_CRITERE2.DATE_FIN_SOUHAITEE - make_interval(years => V_SEUIL_ALERT::integer)
```

the above can then be compared using `<` with `current_date`.

I don't know what the original code in Oracle did, because `DATE_FIN_SOUHAITEE - V_SEUIL_ALERT` would implicitly convert V_SEUIL_ALERT to a `number` which is then taken as **days** to be subtracted from DATE_FIN_SOUHAITEE, *not* years.

If that column indeed stores days rather than years (as stated in the comments), you need to use:

```
make_interval(days => V_SEUIL_ALERT::integer)
```

---

You should **really** take the opportunity of that migration and fix the wrong data type for the column `V_SEUIL_ALERT` to be an integer, numeric or even `interval` if that is what you use it for. **Never** store numbers in VARCHAR columns. That was already a really, really bad idea in Oracle.

Comment: Thank you for your time and explanations. It's working now